# Extract All Integer Rows from Mixed Data Type column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and one of the columns contains both integers and strings. Is there a way to filter on only the rows that have an integer value?

```
df[df['column'].type == int] ?
```

Comment: `df.columns[df.dtypes.astype(str).str.startswith('int')]` basically use `dtypes`, not sure if theres a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['datatype'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: 'int' if type(x) == int else 'str')

df[df['datatype'] == 'int']
```

use lambda function to check and label each row. save that row as a new column and filter on the new column.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df[df['column'].astype(str).str.isdigit()]
```

reference url pandas series

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable//reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html

```
Series.str.isalpha
Check whether all characters are alphabetic.

Series.str.isnumeric
Check whether all characters are numeric.

Series.str.isalnum
Check whether all characters are alphanumeric.

Series.str.isdigit
Check whether all characters are digits.

Series.str.isdecimal
Check whether all characters are decimal.

Series.str.isspace
Check whether all characters are whitespace.

Series.str.islower
Check whether all characters are lowercase.

Series.str.isupper
Check whether all characters are uppercase.

Series.str.istitle
Check whether all characters are titlecase.
```